# How to extract data from xml and persist it to DB using Apache Camel

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel. I have the below XML,which I am consuming from a restful api. I have used JaxB to generate four objects for it. i.e. ConsumerList.java, Consumer.java, Address.java using apache camel.

```
<consumer_list>
        <consumer>
            <name>John</name>
            <address>
                <street>13 B</street>
                <city>Mumbai</city>
            </address>
        </consumer>
        <consumer>
            <name>Paul</name>
            <address>
                <street>82 A</street>
                <city>Delhi</city>
            </address>
        </consumer>

   </consumer_list>
```

Now my requirement is to save those 4 objects to DB. Below is my route from camel-context.xml:

```
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/firstdb"/>
            <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="password" value="xyz"/>
        </bean>

        <!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
        <bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

       <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
       <route id="generateOrder-route">
                <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60000"/>
                <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_QUERY">
                    <constant>dept=7&amp;name=Johnson&amp;offset=0&amp;limit=200</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <to uri="http://example.com/ibp/api/v3/business_partners/search"/>
                <unmarshal>
                    <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="target.jaxb.beans"/>
                </unmarshal>
                <to ???"/>
            </route>
       </camelContext>
```

I have unmarshalled those objects but I have no idea as in how to insert it to database.

Comment: You could start from the documentation for the Camel endpoints [SQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/SQL) and [JDBC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/JDBC).

Comment: I've seen those. My only problem is that I'm not sure, which values should I put in the insert statement. I mean the Address field in the xml has street and city attributes. Same Address class is created by jaxb. Now how do I fetch the street and city attribute and put in the insert statement.

Comment: There is a number of database examples here you can study first: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

Use your normal insert / update queries to persist your data to the DB using apache camel.

Add the below beans to your **SpringConfig.xml** file

```
<!-- JDBC data source bean-->
<bean id="dataSource" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url"
            value="YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING" />
        <property name="username" value="YOUR_USERNAME" />
        <property name="password" value="YOUR_PASSWORD" />
    </bean>

<!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
<bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Set your values that you have unmarshalled into a hashmap according to the names mentioned in your insert query and set this as **exchange.getOut().setBody** in your **MessageProcessor** Class.

Then use this in **CamelRouter.java** by pass this to **transform body**

This **.transform().body()** will set these HashMap values to your Query parameters.

```
from("direct:yourHandleName").to("bean:messsageProcessor?method=setMessageInHashMap")
.transform().body()
        .to("sql:{{----YOUR QUERY HERE----}}")
.log("INFORMATION SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED IN DB").end();
```

Eg.

If Query Contains : `insert into sample_table values (:#sample_val1)`

Map should contain :

```
    hashMapObj.put("sample_val1","<<<YOUR_VALUE>>>");
exchange.getOut().setBody(hashMapObj);
```

Having value for **sample_val1** set in Map

Note : **Query should contain # for the values which should be replaced from HashMap**